# SVD of a 3x3 symmetric matrix shortcuts

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Say there is a 3x3 symmetric matrix such as the following: $$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b & a \\b & b & b \\ a & b & a \end{bmatrix}$$

By being symmetric:$$AA^T=A^TA=A\cdot A =A^2$$

$$\text{Which means that the left & right singular vectors are the same } (\text{eigenvectors of } AA^T \text{ are the same as the eigenvectors of } A^TA \text {)}$$

$$\text{So,one can say: } A=UΣV^T=UΣU^T \\ \text{But that is not the case,there is a different sign at one of the eigenvectors of }V^T \text{.}$$

The question is,why does that happen?Is it supposed to happen?
Turns out,if that vector that was different by a sign is computed manually,using the relation between the left & right singular vectors,the correct sign is given and SVD is complete.

Any ideas?

Comment: The issue is that if you have a symmetric matrix with negative eigenvalues, the singular values are still, by definition, positive. So the orthogonal diagonalization of $A$ does not coincide with its SVD. You can convert it into a SVD by moving the negative sign into one of the matrices $U$ or $V$, which is why you observe there is a sign difference on one of the eigenvectors of $V^T$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition for more